# How to set prestashop database server from docker-compose?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, prestashop

I'm moving my prestashop installation to docker containers. I have a container with prestashop, mariadb and phpmyadmin on Ubuntu. I've set the environment variables as suggested here: https://githubmemory.com/repo/PrestaShop/docker. Here is my `docker-compose`:

```
version: "2"
services:
    prestashop:
        image: prestashop/prestashop
        networks:
            mycustomnetwork:
        ports:
            - 82:80
        links:
            - mariadb:mariadb
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./src/modules:/var/www/html/modules
            - ./src/themes:/var/www/html/themes
            - ./src/override:/var/www/html/override
        environment:
            - PS_DEV_MODE=1
            - DB_SERVER=mariadb
            - DB_USER=user_8
            - DB_PASSWD=password_8
            - DB_NAME=db_8
            - PS_INSTALL_AUTO=0

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        networks:
            mycustomnetwork:
        volumes:
            - db_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_8
            - MYSQL_USER=user_8
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password_8

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        networks:
            mycustomnetwork:
        links:
            - mariadb:mariadb
        ports:
            - 1235:80
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        environment:
            - PMA_HOST=mariadb
            - PMA_USER=user_8
            - PMA_PASSWORD=password_8

volumes:
    db_data:

networks:
    mycustomnetwork:
```

The database works, I can connect to it via phpmyadmin. However in the prestashop logs I get this error:

`Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at line 127 in file classes/db/DbPDO.php`

I modified the code, which threw this error so it prints the variables it uses to try to establish the connection (`$this->server, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database`) and I got this: `localhost user password db`. These values are from `app/config/parameters.php` and not the environment variables I set in the `docker-compose`. What should I do so it uses the values I provided in `docker-compose` instead of the ones from `parameters.php`?

Answer (score 0):

I think Prestashop is reading `app/config/parameters.phhp` file before parsing env vars.
To bypass this, you should force PShop to read conf from env vars.
Use `getenv(<ENV_NAME>)`

`'database_host' => getenv('DB_SERVER')`